# Change order implement div

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change `div` order with jQuery like this:

```
    <div id="container">
    <div class="land">Example A</div>
    <div class="land">Example B</div>
   <div class="land">Example D</div>
    <div class="land">Example C</div>
    <div class="land">Example G</div>
   <div class="land">Example E</div>
    <div class="land">Example F</div>
   <div class="land">...</div>
</div>
```

I have list div ( 10 div).Div with content"Example C" can stand in any position . Can I sorter div with content "Example C" is Always On Top ?

How can I do this ?

Thanks for help

Comment: can we change the .land to different ids for each?

Answer (score 3):

Ordering becomes easy if you add a container div.

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="land">Example A</div>
    <div class="land">Example B</div>
    <div class="land">Example C</div>
</div>
```

```js
var container = $('#container');
var items = container.children('div');
container.append(items.get().reverse());
```

See on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sTt8/).

**Edit:** To make "Example C" appear always on the top, you can use something like:

```js
var container = $('#container');
var top = container.find('div:contains("Example C")');
var items = container.children('div');

container.append(items.get().reverse()).prepend(top);
```

This selects "Example C" by value, but you can change it to select for example by a special class:

```html
<div class="land top">Example C</div>
```

```js
var top = container.find('div.top');
```

See updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sTt8/7/).

**Edit 2:** You changed your question, I don't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve. If you don't need to reverse the order, you can simply use:

```
var container = $('#container');
var top = container.find('div:contains("Example C")');
container.prepend(top);
```

See updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sTt8/9/).

Comment: Can I sorter div with content" Example C" is Always On Top ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "sorting" function natively implemented in jQuery, but it is quite easy to add once !

Take a look at this source :

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

```
$('.lang').sortElements(function(a, b) {
    // This is a text to text comparison, but you can add what ever you want, even random comparison !
    return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parent = $('.land').first().parent();

$('.land').first().appendTo(parent);
$('.land').first().next().prependTo(parent);
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9sTt8/1/)

If you want to making a certain element always on top do not use this way, instead use CSS `z-index` property. Each element with higher `z-index` will be shown in higher level

[jsfiddle about z-index](http://jsfiddle.net/9sTt8/2/)

Comment: Can I sorter div with content" Example C" is Always On Top ?

Comment: @Robert see another jsfiddle in my answer

Comment: I have list div ( 10 div).Div with content"Example C" can stand in any position . Can I sorter div with content "Example C" is Always On Top ? http://jsfiddle.net/9sTt8/4/

Comment: How can you distinguish that div form others?

Comment: Can I sort by content? Or I can addclass(land #id) after sorter it?

Comment: In my opinion giving it an ID may be useful, not?

Comment: I can't, I can .addClass only.

Comment: Okay so give it another class,

Comment: okay, very good. But how can I use addClass 'land-c' for <div class="land">Example C</div> when document load?

Comment: @Robert `$('.land').eq(3).addClass('land-c')`

Answer (score 0):

you can sort divs by using this

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var searchcondition = "Example C";
        var temp = "";
        $(".land:contains('" + searchcondition + "')").each(function (index, value) {

            temp += $(this)[0].outerHTML;
        });

        $(".land").not(":contains('" + searchcondition + "')").each(function (index, value) {
            temp += $(this)[0].outerHTML;
        });
        $("#container").html(temp);

    });
```

The "example C " always on top and remain div comes after it